# C++ row and columns matrix manipulation

Tags: c++, matrix, swap

I've created a 2D matrix as a vector of vectors like this :

```
vector<vector<int>> mat;
```

now I need to swap the row and columns of my matrix for example :

```
row 0 swapped with row 4 
column 5 swapped with column 1
```

the rows aren't a problem since there is the swap() function of the stl library. Exchanging rows though seems quite problematic because, of course, they are not considered as one atomic structure. so at this point I'm really stuck... I've considered doing it brutally swapping every element of the rows I'm interested in, but it seems quite inelegant. Any idea of how I could achieve my goal ?

Comment: I do not see alternatives, but I see other problems. Do you take for granted (a precondition) that all rows have same size?

Comment: yes, sorry. the matrix is square.

Comment: By "Exchanging rows.." you mean columns right?

Comment: No you can't. You must perform swap operation for each vector in vector.

Comment: There is no way around manually swapping each value for this memory layout.

Comment: no. i mean that i intend to exchange both rows and columns. in the first case life is easy ( swap ) in the second it's not

Comment: If you're going to use this for more complex tasks, a more elegant and efficient way is to use a library such as _eigen_ . For a simple home-made solution I don't see alternatives, too. Probably having an unrolled matrix in a single vector will make row and column operations similar, but not necessarily easier

Comment: @beaker hum, i don't get what you mean precisely. can you try to explain it with an example ?

Comment: i also tought that i could do row's swaps and then transpose the matrix and do the column's ones.

Comment: FalconUA's update does pretty much the same thing, though I was suggesting using a second permutation vector for the rows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider "elenance" as a STL function that can do all this stuff for you, then there's no function like this. The aim of STL is not about making your code as simple as possible, the creators of C++ only add to STL things that:

- Is really hard to implement with the current language's instrument
- Things that need a special support from your compiler (special optimization, etc.)
- Some elements that became common

So, just implement by your own.

If you don't want to use `for (;;)` loops because it's not "elegant" at some point, then you can do something like this:

```
/* swapping column i and j */
std::vector<std::vector<T>> mat;
std::for_each(mat.begin(), mat.end(), [i,j](std::vector<int>& a)
        { std::swap(a[i], a[j]); });
```

---

**Update:** If the speed is important for you and you want to swap columns as fast as swapping rows (in O(1) ), then you can use this implementation (that takes extra space)):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;

/* preprocessing */    
std::vector<int> permutation(mat[0].size());
std::iota(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), 0);

/* now, if you need to get the element mat[i][j] */
mat_i_j = mat[i][ permutation[j] ];

/* if you want to swap column i and j */
std::swap(permutation[i], permutation[j]);
```

Comment: btw std::vector< std::vector<int>& > mat; give me c2535 error in visual studio

Comment: @darkpirate Oh I think it's because vector of references is a little bit more tricky. Also, my mistake - you don't need to use vector of references, the standard implementation of [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) calls [`std::vector::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/), and it's time complexity is constant. So just use `vector<vector<int>>` as usual (I also edited my answer).

Comment: oh, i get it. You basically use an array of indices to "emulate" the swap. clever.

Comment: but on further thinking, in this way you're not swapping anithing. i mean let's say i want to pass the elaborated matrix somewhere ( for example another class )  i'd have to rewrite the whole matrix down for a computational cost of  n^2... am i right ?